# Applying a function to all buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im working on a quick script to apply an alert and redirect message to all anchors and buttons on a page. So far, I have this working for all anchors:

```
document.querySelector('body')
.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if
        (event.target.tagName === 'A' || event.target.tagName === 'button') { 
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("test");
       window.open('http://www.test.com', '_self');
    }
});
```

When i try to apply the same idea to all buttons (see after the || in the script), it does not apply. Am I missing something?

Comment: `"button" !== "BUTTON"` [`Element.tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName): _"On HTML elements in DOM trees flagged as HTML documents, tagName returns the element name in the **uppercase form**."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.target.tagName` results are capitalized.

**`A`** **`BUTTON`** **`TEXTAREA`** etc.